# Flutter, converting a low value double to currency

Tags: flutter, dart, currency-formatting

I want to convert a low value double like (**0.0003009585**) to show as a currency (**$0.0003**).

Intl package NumberFormat() will show it as $0 for different currency formats.

Tried different RegexExp did'nt work.

**These code also doesnot work**

```
String numToCurrency(double num) {
  final String numThreeZero = num.toStringAsFixed(2);

  final String numWithComma = NumberFormat.decimalPattern().format(double.parse(numThreeZero));



  if (numWithComma == '0') {
    final strNum = num.toString();

    String fixedNum = '';

    for (int i = 0; i < strNum.length; i++) {
      if (strNum[i] == '0' || strNum[i] == '.') continue;

      fixedNum = num.toStringAsFixed(i);
    }

    return fixedNum;
  } else {
    return numWithComma;
  }
}
```

Comment: you want to roundoff as soon as you find valid number after decimal or you want to round off at 4th digit?

Comment: I want to round off as soon I found a digit > 0, after decimal point. as I gave an example above. i.e 0.002088 -> 0.002

Answer (score 0):

Two logical mistakes I found and here is how to solve them.

Firstly, `num.toStringAsFixed(2)` will round the value to two decimal places and return a string representation of the number. However, this does not add any commas to the number.

Secondly, `NumberFormat.decimalPattern()` will format the number with commas based on the user's locale. It does not add a currency symbol or format the number as a currency.

To format the number as a currency with two decimal places, you can use the `NumberFormat.currency()` method. Here is an example of how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
String numToCurrency(double num) {
  final formatter = NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'en_US', decimalDigits: 4, symbol: '\$');
  return formatter.format(num);
}
```

This will format the number as a currency with four decimal places (if available), with the currency symbol as $.

If you want to show only two decimal places and remove trailing zeros, you can modify the code as follows:

```
String numToCurrency(double num) {
  final formatter = NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'en_US', decimalDigits: 2, symbol: '\$');
  final formattedString = formatter.format(num);
  return formattedString.replaceAll(RegExp(r'(?<=\d)0{2}\b|\.\d*?0+\b'), '');
}
```

This will remove any trailing zeros after the decimal point and also remove any trailing `.00`.

Comment: These works but for specifically the value in the example but I want the decimalDigits to not be specific to 4 or 2 but based on the input I provide. As after decimal point it should show the value till it hits a number > 0. i.e 0.00204 to 0.002

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't mind some maths :-)

You can use log to find the first non-zero digit.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  final f = 0.0003009585;
  final l = log(f) / log(10);

  if (l < 0) {  // change this logic to l < -5 or some other number as per requirement
    print(f.toStringAsFixed(-l.floor()));
  }
}
```

Output:
`0.0003`

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would be a simple solution

```
public static String numToCurrency(double number, String digits){

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(digits); // digits variable is optional.. you can set prefix like "0.0000"
    return "$" + df.format(number);
}
```